# How can we infer from the combined p-value of Fisher's method whether the null hypotheses are all true?

Tags: combining-p-values

Using the R package oolong ([oolong](https://github.com/chainsawriot/oolong)), I used Fisher's method to combine the p-values of three binomial tests. I have difficulty understanding the combined p-value. I understood it to mean that the combined p-value tells me whether all null hypotheses were true. What exactly needs to be assessed for this? Reading this [Understanding Fisher's combined test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31070/understanding-fishers-combined-test), I have two guesses:

1. If the combined p-value is below the significance level chosen for
   the individual binomial tests, the null hypotheses for at least one test
   can be rejected.
2. Since Fisher's method is based on the chi-square distribution, the critical value must
   be calculated depending on the degrees of freedom, as in the chi-square test. If the
   combined p-value is above the critical value, the null hypotheses for each test can be
   rejected.

I know that this is a very basic question, but unfortunately I don't know much about statistics and would be really grateful if someone could help me. Any links to tutorials or papers would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "whether all null hypotheses were true" There's only one single hypothesis. What is multiple are the number of samples/data-sets and the method is to combine those into a single sample/data-set.

Comment: In addition, we typically don't infer whether a hypothesis is true, and more like whether it is false. See for example [Why do statisticians say a non-significant result means "you can't reject the null" as opposed to accepting the null hypothesis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85903/)

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171742/test-for-significant-excess-of-significant-p-values-across-multiple-comparisons/246059#246059 help you?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods for combining p-values and all work (approximately) only in the circumstance where more than one dataset are available to interrogate a singular null hypothesis. (As @Sextus Empiricus said.) The combined p-value gives you an (approximate) index of how strongly the data in combination argue against that single null hypothesis as a significance test. You can also use the relationship between the combined p-value and a predetermined threshold to 'decide' whether to reject the null hypothesis if you prefer the hypothesis test approach.

If you were to 'combine' p-values from tests of differing null hypotheses there certainly would be reason to wonder at what exactly is being tested.